# Can OAuth work with mobile phone applications?

Tags: oauth, mobile-phones

Can we make OAuth work from applications on mobile phones where there is no browser available?

Without a browser, is it still possible for a user to approve the token requests (so that the consumer can proceed to fetch the protected resources from the service provider)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838765/openid-authentication-from-an-installed-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973205/j2me-oauth-2-fo-connecting-to-google-apis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113999/oauth-twitter-and-blackberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chris Messina answered this question](http://getsatisfaction.com/oauth/topics/can_we_make_oauth_work_from_applications_on_mobile_phones_where_there_is_no_browser_available?utm_medium=widget&utm_source=widget_oauth) referring to [this blog post](http://www.hueniverse.com/hueniverse/2009/02/beyond-the-oauth-web-redirection-flow.html) that explains the possibilities.

Comment: These links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934187/oauth-secrets-in-mobile-apps) also has some insight as to using oauth in mobile apps.