# oauth for mobile application

Tags: mobile, oauth, oauth-provider

I have a server(web) application and have exposed RESTful webservices so that third party companies can develop thier mobile applications on top of it. I want to have oAuth for authentication.

I understand how oAuth works for third party websites, but when it comes to mobile applications, I am not sure how the redirect and callback and sharing of the secret will work?

Comment: Here are some related questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838765/openid-authentication-from-an-installed-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973205/j2me-oauth-2-fo-connecting-to-google-apis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113999/oauth-twitter-and-blackberry

Answer (score 0):

The apps would probably best use embedded WebKit -views ([UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on iOS/[WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) on Android. Don't know about others, but there are most certainly equivalents on BlackBerry etc) to do the request to the server and possibly accomodate the login form needed.