# OAuth Twitter and Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, twitter, oauth

I have a j2me project on blackberry that needs to connect to twitter.  I did most of the hard stuff already, I've got an api that guided me through to the access token pretty easily.  Now I can't seem to get the authentication to work with a status update in REST.

I know my tokens are valid because if I run a GET method like verify credentials, it's fine, everything is valid.  But POST messages are just confusing me. Am I supposed to pass in a whole consumer key, signature, oauth version, etc every time I update a status?  Or do I just pass the access token? Are they all supposed to be POST variables or just the ones specified in the twitter api as parameters.  The twitter api documentation has left me completely lost.

If someone had a link to a site that had examples of all of these messages put into plain text NOT in an library as 99% of tutorials for this situation are, it would be really helpful.