# Hiding oauth secrets

Tags: security, encryption, oauth

I'm building an (amateur) application that uses the Twitter API, which supports authentication via the OAuth protocol.

Part of the OAuth sign-in process involves each application being assigned a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret (both strings), which are used to generate signatures for communication with the Twitter server.

The Twitter dev guide explicitly states that one should 'Keep the "Consumer secret" a secret. This key should never be human-readable in your application.'. This is obviously important, as if a malicious individual obtains your credentials, they can impersonate your app.

However, I do not see how this can be achieved. In order for the application to use the string, it must be accessible to the app somehow (either directly coded into the app, stored in a bundled database, or accessible via a linked web service) - and if it's accessible to the app, it must be accessible to the user. It can be obfuscated by splitting, character-shifting, etc., but not (as far as I can see) in any way that can't be undone.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934234/1040915) SO answer confirms my suspicions that this is a problem - I was wondering if there had been any progress since it was posted in December '09?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mobile devices is that is in the users hands. And with enough time/effort the user can pull any data out of the device. It isn't an OAuth security problem, it is an overall security problem that there really isn't an answer for.

Comment: I see your point - but isn't this even more of a problem on desktop devices, on which custom software can be installed to sniff on communications?

Comment: Anytime that secret information (such as client ID and client secret) are on a user's machine (desktop or mobile) then it can be found.

Comment: The problem with client secrets is that once the user has it, they not only have access to the account the device is on, but potentially all other accounts as well (if a corresponding access token can be sniffed).