# The "right" way to do oAuth from a mobile client

Tags: node.js, oauth, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, passport.js

I am building a cross platform mobile application (using the Xamarian tools, MonoTouch / MonoDroid). I am trying to work through the authentication workflow and am running into a stumbling block. I have searched all over for a clear answer and have yet to find it.

Here is an overview of my current setup.

I have a web site built in nodejs.
I use passport.js to do oAuth login on the web site. This works great, users can login to my site using Twitter or Facebook.

Now I want to extend this same login functionality to my mobile clients.

I see 2 options

1. Embed the app id and app secret's in the mobile clients and make direct oAuth calls to FB or Twitter from the mobile app
2. Proxy the oAuth calls through my existing nodejs web server (keeping the secret keys on the server)

Option 2 appears to be the preferred way (as it avoids having to "ship" the secret in the mobile apps).

I have the proxy approach mostly working.

1. I open a WebView in my mobile client and point it at `http://mysever/auth/twitter`
2. This runs through my existing passport.js code and redirects the mobile WebView over to the Twitter login page.
3. The user then enters their creds on the twitter webpage on the device.
4. Twitter then calls my oAuth callback URL (which is my nodejs web server).
5. My server and Twitter handle the back a fourth handshake of obtaining the user profile information (**As I understand it, this is the key to this approach, my server and twitter handle the handshake, the mobile client doesn't have to do anything or pass any tokens during this process**)

**Here is my problem**:

1. It is this last step that stumps me. Once the handshake is complete on my server I have the user information I need on the server and **need to send it back to the mobile client application**

   I can't figure out any way in the WebView control to grab the response object and grab a cookie, or header value (for instance) (this seems true for Android and iOS). I don't think it is platform specific. I think I am trying to do something that a WebView widget in mobile platforms just don't suport. It makes me think I am missing something obvious.

The only thing I have figured out is to have my web server "redirect" the mobile client browser to a fake URL that has the user info in the querystring. Something like myapp://info?userid=1234

Then in the mobile app I can hijack the URL loading and grab this url and get the data I need. I can then stash this userinfo, close the WebView control and move on to a native screen in my mobile application and user the userinfo in any subsequent REST calls to my nodejs server as a means of identifying the user.

This is massively kludgy for multiple reasons. The biggest of which is that the url is sent over the wire unencrypted and has all the data in plain text.

**There has to be a better way to get the data from the web server back to the mobile client?**

Or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: what approach did you finally settle on? I'm stuck in the same dilemma with your Option 2 being the idealistic approach.

Comment: Honestly, I never found a solution that worked well. The generally accepted thing seems to be to ship the secret in the mobile app. People just seem to bake it into the app and don't care much beyond that.

Comment: Anyone else just feeling like OAuth is a complete mess of interpretation and half arsed implementations?

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to implement oauth for Xamarin, both for iOS and Android, is using [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth). The starter documentation for the client is [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/GettingStarted.md). I think it should maintain everything securely and you will not have to worry about having to use your node server as a proxy.

You will need to provide your Application ID as part of the calls, but I don't there are too many or any security issues to worry about there.

I know this is going against what you already have implemented, but maybe this could help simplify things a bit.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen this library. thanks for the link. It looks like this is basically the same thing that RestSharp offers (which is effectively my option 1). For oAuth1 (Twitter) I think this means I will have to embed my app secret into the mobile deployment package right?

Comment: Ah, yep, RestSharp has the same OAuth functionality. For OAuth1, there is not be a lot of great options. Either, embed or go for a proxy, like what you had started. If you do embed, you could obfuscate the keys or try to store them in a secure location, but there is no guarantee that they won't get stolen. I think this post is a fairly good overview on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934187/oauth-secrets-in-mobile-apps.

Comment: Yeah I read that thread. But there really isn't a solution offered. Except to say that oAuth isn't the right solution for client applications. I am thinking more and more that just punting on oAuth is a better solution for mobile apps

Comment: Agreed. I think OAuth 2 makes it feasible, but for clients where you still need to distribute your keys, it just feels a little wrong.

Comment: Well I am glad I am not the only one with that feeling. For a while I thought I was just missing something obvious. Now I think the answer is oAuth sucks for mobile clients :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same dilemma that I have been dealing with.
This is how I currently deal with it.
In my app the client can come directly or via another service such as facebook which is my main one and hence the one which I have concentrated on.

Facebook can either redirect via a POST (desk apps) or a GET (mobile).

I check the initial request so see if has a service identifier - here is the facebook GET for example.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var paraUrl = URL.parse(req.url,true).query;
//The fb_source is shown - 
//i need to go striaght to the facebook authorization since 
//its coming from
//from a mobile device.
if (paraUrl.fb_source){
res.redirect('/auth/facebook'); //this is the passport part
return;
}
res.sendfile('index.html');
}
```

The facebook POST is slightly different in that you get an access token encode in base64url. The GET gives you a code which you can exchange for an access token but I had problems with it and just opted for tying into the passport system.

If a client comes direct I check for the session or a encrypted cookie which ties into the local strategy. This then checks the db for an access token which can used to access the facebook api for example.

If a client is unrecognised they are given the option to authenticate via facebook, google etc.

The main thing is that only 2 pieces of information are stored with the client, the passport session id and my app user id

connect.sid - encypted cookie

userId - encypted cookie

I would be interested to find out how other people are dealing with issue

Comment: How are you getting the connect.sid and the userid back to the mobile application? Are you able to grab the response object from the Mobile browser somehow?

Comment: These are set using encrypted cookies so they are returned for every request. The connect.sid is only good for the length of the app but I set my user id to be alive for two weeks

Comment: So are you able to get to the Cookie jar object and pull the encrypted cookie from the browser widget (WebView) or are you staying in the browser context for the duration of your mobile client?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clearer. Its in the browser context for the duration.