# What's the right OAuth 2.0 flow for a mobile app

Tags: security, mobile, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement delegated authorization in a Web API for mobile apps using OAuth 2.0. According to specification, the implicit grant flow does not support refresh tokens, which means once an access token is granted for an specific period of time, the user must grant permissions to the app again once the token expires or it is revoked.

I guess this is a good scenario for some javascript code running on a browser as it is mentioned in the specification. I am trying to minimize the times the user must grant permissions to the app to obtain a token, so it looks like the Authorization Code flow is a good option as it supports refresh tokens.

However, this flow seems to rely heavily on a web browser for performing the redirections. I am wondering if this flow is still a good option for a mobile app if a embedded web browser is used. Or should I go with the implicit flow ?

Comment: The question would be - is it like the highest priority that the user never ever has to type in a password again after the first login?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my requirement. The user should type the password just once. However, I don't want to setup a token with infinite lifetime and keep it in the mobile app, as that would go against the ability of revoking the token. (Unless I add some logic in the mobile app to detect that the request was unauthorized so I request a new token after that)

Comment: You can add a token with infinite lifetime and still revoke it. And yes, the app logic should be able to detect that. RFC 6750 defines a way to check if the error is due to a revoked token.

Comment: Please avoid web views (unless you own the full stack and are not using social login) which open the possibility of compromising passwords. When I am asked for credentials by a third-party embedded user-agent I would uninstall the app. Some APIs now even ban such integrations such as this one https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/ I have provided another answer to further clarify some of these concepts (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38582630/752167)

Answer (score 113):

Clarification: Mobile App = Native App

As stated in other comments and a few sources online, implicit seems like a natural fit for mobile apps, however the best solution is not always clear cut (and in fact implicit is not recommended for reasons discussed below).

**Native App OAuth2 Best Practises**

Whatever approach you choose (there are a few trade offs to consider), you should pay attention to the best practices as outlined here for Native Apps using OAuth2: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252

Consider the following options

**Implicit**

Should I use implicit?

To quote from Section 8.2 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-8.2

> The OAuth 2.0 implicit grant authorization flow (defined in Section 4.2 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749]) generally works with the practice of performing the authorization request in the browser and receiving the authorization response via URI-based inter-app communication.
> However, as the implicit flow cannot be protected by PKCE [RFC7636] (which is required in Section 8.1), **the use of the Implicit Flow with native apps is NOT RECOMMENDED**.
>
> Access tokens granted via the implicit flow also cannot be refreshed without user interaction, making the authorization code grant flow --
> which can issue refresh tokens -- the more practical option for native app authorizations that require refreshing of access tokens.

**Authorization Code**

If you do go with Authorization Code, then one approach would be to proxy through your own web server component which enriches the token requests with the client secret to avoid storing it on the distributed app on devices.

Excerpt below from: https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/

> The Authorization Code Grant flow is recommended for applications that
> have a web service. This flow requires server-to-server communication
> using an application's client secret.
>
> Note: Never put your client secret in distributed code, such as apps
> downloaded through an app store or client-side JavaScript.
>
> Applications that do not have a web service should use the Implicit
> Grant flow.

**Conclusion**

The final decision should factor in your desired user experience but also your appetite for risk after doing a proper risk assessment of your shortlisted approaches and better understanding the implications.

A great read is here https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/

Another one is https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth-native-apps/ which states

> The current industry best practice is to use the Authorization Flow
> while omitting the client secret, and to use an external user agent to
> complete the flow. An external user agent is typically the device’s
> native browser, (with a separate security domain from the native app,)
> so that the app cannot access the cookie storage or inspect or modify
> the page content inside the browser.

**PKCE Consideration**

You should also consider PKCE which is described here https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/

Specifically, if you are also implementing the Authorization Server then https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth-native-apps/checklist-server-support-native-apps/ states that you should

- Allow clients to register custom URL schemes for their redirect URLs.
- Support loopback IP redirect URLs with arbitrary port numbers in order to support desktop apps.
- Don’t assume native apps can keep a secret. Require all apps to declare whether they are public or confidential, and only issue client secrets to confidential apps.
- Support the PKCE extension, and require that public clients use it.
- Attempt to detect when the authorization interface is embedded in a native app’s web view, instead of launched in a system browser, and reject those requests.

**Web Views Consideration**

There are many examples in the wild using Web Views i.e. an embedded user-agent but this approach should be avoided (especially when the app is not first-party) and in some cases may result in you being banned from using an API as the excerpt below from [here](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/) demonstrates

> Any attempt to embed the OAuth 2.0 authentication page will result in
> your application being banned from the Fitbit API.
>
> For security consideration, the OAuth 2.0 authorization page must be
> presented in a dedicated browser view. Fitbit users can only confirm
> they are authenticating with the genuine Fitbit.com site if they have
> the tools provided by the browser, such as the URL bar and Transport
> Layer Security (TLS) certificate information.
>
> For native applications, this means the authorization page must open
> in the default browser. Native applications can use custom URL schemes
> as redirect URIs to redirect the user back from the browser to the
> application requesting permission.
>
> iOS applications may use the SFSafariViewController class instead of
> app switching to Safari. Use of the WKWebView or UIWebView class is
> prohibited.
>
> Android applications may use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of app
> switching to the default browser. Use of WebView is prohibited.

To further clarify, here is a quote from [this section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wdenniss-oauth-native-apps-02#section-5.1) of a previous draft of the best practise link provided above

> Embedded user-agents, commonly implemented with web-views, are an
> alternative method for authorizing native apps.  They are however
> unsafe for use by third-parties by definition.  They involve the user
> signing in with their full login credentials, only to have them
> downscoped to less powerful OAuth credentials.
>
> Even when used by trusted first-party apps, embedded user-agents
> violate the principle of least privilege by obtaining more powerful
> credentials than they need, potentially increasing the attack surface.
>
> In typical web-view based implementations of embedded user-agents, the
> host application can: log every keystroke entered in the form to
> capture usernames and passwords; automatically submit forms and bypass
> user-consent; copy session cookies and use them to perform
> authenticated actions as the user.
>
> Encouraging users to enter credentials in an embedded web-view without
> the usual address bar and other identity features that browsers have
> makes it impossible for the user to know if they are signing in to the
> legitimate site, and even when they are, it trains them that it's OK
> to enter credentials without validating the site first.
>
> Aside from the security concerns, web-views do not share the
> authentication state with other apps or the system browser, requiring
> the user to login for every authorization request and leading to a
> poor user experience.
>
> Due to the above, use of embedded user-agents is NOT RECOMMENDED,
> except where a trusted first-party app acts as the external user-
> agent for other apps, or provides single sign-on for multiple first-
> party apps.
>
> Authorization servers SHOULD consider taking steps to detect and block
> logins via embedded user-agents that are not their own, where
> possible.

Some interesting points are also raised here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179756/why-are-developers-using-embedded-user-agents-for-3rd-party-auth-what-are-the-a

Comment: Google are removing support for webviews on April 20, 2017 https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html?m=1

Comment: FYI the document references in the start of this Answer if not draft anymore OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252

Comment: Thanks @KostiantynSokolinskyi, edited accordingly with link for rfc which is no longer draft

Comment: @MattC What is the best way to implement registration of a new user? Should we do it within the app or on the IDP? Is it possible to auto-login the user post register?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187173/oidc-register-auto-login-flow-for-mobile-apps

Comment: Sorry I am confused about some details... Could you please have a look? Thanks! link ---> https://stackoverflow.com/q/61313694/4619958

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a clear answer to this question. However, here are the options that I've identified:

- If it is ok to ask the user for his/her credentials, then use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-9). However, this may not be possible for some reasons, namely

  - Usability or security policies forbid the insertion of the password directly at the app
  - The authentication process is delegated on an external Identity Provider and must be performed via an HTTP redirect-based flow (e.g. OpenID, SAMLP or WS-Federation)
- If usage of a browser based flow is required, then use the [Authorization Code Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-8). Here, the definition of the `redirect_uri` is a major challenge, for which there are the following options:

  - Use the technique described in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp, where a special `redirect_uri` (e.g. `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`) signals the authorization endpoint to show the authorization code instead of redirecting back to the client app. The user can manually copy this code or the app can try to obtain it from the HTML document title.
  - Use a `localhost` server at the device (the port management may not be easy).
  - Use a custom URI scheme (e.g. `myapp://...`) that when dereferenced triggers a registered "handler" (the details depend on the mobile platform).
  - If available, use a special "web view", such as the [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025) on Windows 8, to control and access the HTTP redirect responses.

Hope this helps

Pedro

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the input!. Yes, it looks like the Authorization Code Flow with the custom URI scheme or the Web View seems to be the best option here.

Comment: It all depends on if you want the client to type the password into a web view or in the client app. If possible, I would prefer the client app - then immediately exchange the secret with an access/refresh token.

Comment: Thanks Dominick!. My customer is using ADFS to authenticate the users, so they want to enter the credentials in the login page. The web view will work for them

Comment: I'm curious why you would recommend the "authorization code flow"? Wouldn't you would need client_secret and client_id to exchange the code for an access_token? I thought the "implicit" flow was designed for these scenarios, because it doesn't require secrets to be stored in the device.

Comment: implicit does not support refresh tokens OOB. In Pablo's scenario - I clearly would recommend RO flow. Sounds like company deployed apps against the same company backend.

Comment: I guess the implicit flow would prevent things like this to happen, right ? http://threatpost.com/twitter-oauth-api-keys-leaked-030713/

Comment: Theoretically, one can use code flow with public clients. However, there should be a way to create per-installation clients, where a client_secret is assigned for a specific installation. I was hoping that the dynamic client registration spec would introduce some support for this, but it does not appear so.

Comment: @EugenioPace I also recommend the same actually. You don't have to waste time with making your own login form this way. This way, the login interface is specific to the service you are authenticating with and this makes the user feel more comfortable.

Comment: @EugenioPace is correct here
And please avoid web views which open the possibility of compromising passwords. When I am asked for credentials by an embedded user-agent I would uninstall the app. Some APIs now even ban such integrations such as this one https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/
I have provided another answer to further clarify some of these concepts (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38582630/752167)

Comment: Sorry I am confused about some details... Could you please have a look? Thanks! link ---> https://stackoverflow.com/q/61313694/4619958

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR:** Use Authorization Code Grant with [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/)

**1. Implicit Grant Type**

The implicit grant type is quite popular with mobile apps. But it was not meant to be used like this. There are security concerns around the redirect. [Justin Richer states](https://medium.com/@justinsecurity/mobile-apps-and-oauths-implicit-flow-68e72c6515a1):

> The problem comes when you realize that unlike with a remote server
> URL, there is no reliable way to ensure that the binding between a
> given redirect URI and a specific mobile application is honored. Any
> app on the device can try to insert itself into the redirection
> process and cause it to serve the redirect URI. And guess what: if
> you’ve used the implicit flow in your native application, then you
> just handed the attacker your access token. There’s no recovery from
> that point — they’ve got the token and they can use it.

And together with the fact, that it does not let you refresh the access token, better avoid it.

**2. Authorization Code Grant Type**

The authorization code grant requires a client secret. But you should not store sensitive information in the source code of your mobile app. People can extract them. To not expose the client secret, you have to run a server as a middleman as [Facebook writes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#appsecret):

> We recommend that App Access Tokens should only be used directly from
> your app's servers in order to provide the best security. For native
> apps, we suggest that the app communicates with your own server and
> the server then makes the API requests to Facebook using the App
> Access Token.

Not an ideal solution but there is new, a better way to do OAuth on mobile devices: *Proof Key for Code Exchange*

**3. Authorization Code Grant Type with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange)**

Out of the limitations, a new technique was created that let you use the Authorization Code without a client secret. You can read the full [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) or [this short introduction](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/).

> PKCE (RFC 7636) is a technique to secure public clients that don't use
> a client secret.
>
> It is primarily used by native and mobile apps, but the technique can
> be applied to any public client as well. It requires additional
> support by the authorization server, so it is only supported on
> certain providers.

*from https://oauth.net/2/pkce/*

Answer (score -4):

Using a webview in your mobile application should be an affordable way to implement OAuth2.0 protocol on Android platform.

As for redirect_uri field, I think `http://localhost` is a good choice and you don't have to port a HTTP server inside your application, because you can override the implementation of `onPageStarted` function in the `WebViewClient` class and stop loading the web page from `http://localhost` after you check the `url` parameter.

```
public void onPageStarted(final WebView webView, final String url,
        final Bitmap favicon) {}
```

Comment: Best practices for Native Apps using OAuth2: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wdenniss-oauth-native-apps

Comment: As Matt C said, above. Web Views are a bad idea for mobile apps - they are insecure, allow the app to gain access to the credentials (so no more secure than RO) and don't allow users to verify domain and TLS certificates. Use Auth Code grant type with a custom URI handler, and make sure you're using [Proof Code for Key Exchange (PKCE)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636) to stop malicious apps on your phone intercepting the auth code and getting access to your API.

Comment: Updated version of the draft OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps best practices document is at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps

Answer (score -5):

The smoothest user experience for authentication, and the easiest to implement is to embed a webview in your app. Process the responses received by the webview from the authentication point and detect error (user cancel) or approval (and extract token from url query parameters).
And I think you can actually do that in all platforms. I have successfully made this work for the following: ios, android, mac, windows store 8.1 apps, windows phone 8.1 app. I did this for the following services: dropbox, google drive, onedrive, box, basecamp. For the non-windows platforms, I was using Xamarin which supposedly does not expose the entire platform specific APIs, yet it did expose enough for making this possible. So it is a pretty accessible solution, even from a cross platform perspective, and you don't have to worry about the ui of the authentication form.

Comment: Whilst providing a convenient user experience, we will see the industry move away from this approach. As web views open the possibility of compromising passwords, when I am asked for credentials by an embedded user-agent I would uninstall the app. Some APIs now even ban such integrations such as this one https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/

Comment: Best practices for Native Apps using OAuth2: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wdenniss-oauth-native-apps

Comment: I don't see how could an oauth enabled service ban this approach. It is undetectable and safe... Some oauth enabled services provide platform specific clients to ease the authentification, and such clients actually do what I have described here (show an embedded webview and track url changes). The best practice you linked, recommends the same thing: use system browser or embedded webview. What argument are you attacking from my response? it is unclear.

Comment: No attack intended, just highlighting the issue. The link says there are the 2 approaches you mention but only an external user-agent can be considered secure, specifically it says the options for Native apps are "via an embedded user-agent, or an external    user-agent.     This document recommends external user-agents like in-app browser    tabs as the only secure and usable choice for OAuth."

Comment: Further quote "In typical web-view based implementations of embedded user-agents,    the host application can: log every keystroke entered in the form to    capture usernames and passwords; automatically submit forms and    bypass user-consent"......."use of embedded user-agents is NOT RECOMMENDED, except where a trusted first-party app acts as the external user-    agent for other apps, or provides single sign-on for multiple first-    party apps. Authorization servers SHOULD consider taking steps to detect and block logins via embedded user-agents that are not their own, where possible."

Comment: Updated version of the draft OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps best practices document is at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps