# Which OAuth2 Grant type is suitable for Mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth 2.0 for my Mobile application(React native) authentication.There are several grant types like Autherization code flow and Password grant flow in OAuth. But which one is suitable for my mobile application.

Comment: Ramesh, have you tried to search for the answer? There is the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427707/whats-the-right-oauth-2-0-flow-for-a-mobile-app) and an [RFC document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252) about it, which is good to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right OAuth 2.0 flow for a mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427707/whats-the-right-oauth-2-0-flow-for-a-mobile-app)