# Obfuscate iPhone Password

Tags: ios, oauth, obfuscation

If I need to obfuscate an iPhone password that is hardcode (Oauth Client Identifier and Client Secret), would this be a way to do it?

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSString *b = @"b";
NSString *c = @"c";
NSString *d = @"d";
NSString *e = @"e";
NSString *f = @"f";
NSString *g = @"g";
NSString *h = @"h";
NSString *i = @"i";
/*    hidden     */
NSString *w = @"w";
NSString *x = @"x";
NSString *y = @"y";
NSString *z = @"z";

NSString *pwd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d];
```

I know obfuscate isn't recommended but after reading this [OAuth secrets in mobile apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934187/oauth-secrets-in-mobile-apps) it seems like the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with `clang -O3`, only the letters that are actually used in the password get included in the .o file.  You should include some code that pretends to use the rest of the alphabet, such as another call to `+ stringWithFormat` whose results are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You could always encrypt the text in question offline, store the encrypted version in the app, then at the point where you need it, decrypt it. That way it (at least) isn't in plain text in the app. Even your mechanism above will likely produce a pattern in the binary.