# HIPAA compliant android application

Tags: android, encryption, hipaa, sqlcipher-android

Building an app to be HIPAA compliant, I wonder how is it possible to store access token to the remote server, and/or have a local SQL encrypted local database (SQLCipher for example).

Considering the nature of HIPAA requirements, I can only conclude the appropriate location of a key can only be on the server, and not locally on the mobile device:

> Section §164.312 of the HIPAA standards says the following:
>
> (a)(1) Standard: Access control. Implement technical policies and
>   procedures for electronic information systems that maintain electronic
>   protected health information to allow access only to those persons or
>   software programs that have been granted access rights as specified in
>   §164.308(a)(4).

So to be more specific,

1) Assuming a person with access to the phone can eventually extract a key/access token, does that mean that local key storage is not HIPAA compliant?

2) How can a messaging app be HIPAA compliant? Since the user is not prompted to enter a password every time the app is opened, it means the access token is saved somewhere locally on the phone.

Comment: [AFAIK (see my answer here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609526/store-client-secret-securely/31352769#31352769) you can't store 100% securely a token in an Android device. I'm posting this as a comment, because I have the feeling that, to answer properly your question, you should be a lawyer ;)

Comment: @jmm, thanks for the answer! As a simple example, even knowing how whatsapp store the user access token would be great :)